# Automatic ftp transfer like Fling?

Tags: software-recommendation, ftp

I'm a web-developer, I'm using win7, but now I want to try ubuntu, I want to ask if is on the ubuntu any software which automatically upload the folder content to the server. For example if I save a file that automatically upload to the server through ftp.
On the windows I'm using [Fling](http://www.nchsoftware.com/ftp/index.html) 
Is there any alternative on ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file manager that comes with Ubuntu, which is called Nautilus, lets you mount a FTP server folder as a Drive. You can then modify the files just as if they were on your computer and as soon as you save them the server copy is updated. (I've never used Fling, but this sounds just like it.) I've used it before with SFTP (basically a secure version of FTP) and it works great for web development.
To do this, just open the file browser and go to the "File" menu and click "Connect to server...". In the window that comes up pick "FTP (with login)" as the services type, enter your details (username, password, server), and click Connect. (If you check Add bookmark and enter a name for it, this server will show in the sidebar of the File Browser so you just click it to connect to the server even after a reboot.)

[image: Screenshot showing steps for FTP in nautilus]

Comment: Unfortunatly some programs have problems saving to or opening from [GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) mounts.

Comment: This would be my favourite method too but it does not always work.

Comment: SASS compilers don't want to work with this and regular FTP account.

Answer (score 4):

There are so many ways to do this :-)

1 of them I have seen used at my office is [ftp-upload](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ftp-upload) [image: Install ftp-upload].

[image]

Basically you set up a script and let `cron` do all the hard work.

Advantage of this is that it works with any program you code with: all it requires is that you save it in the location the ftp-upload script is checking for files.

We use PCs to edit files, save them on our own server so we can check our internal webserver (basically it's the Nautilus mounting method you approved) and update our remote webserver with this script at 18:00.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/). Just mount your FTP directories somewhere in .. maybe `~/Projects/` and start working on these files.